# The constructor File(Path) is undefined

Tags: java

I have an error in this code:

Source:

```
        System.out.println("Load");
        Path path = Paths.get("BillboardHot100.csv");
        Path textpath = path;
        user1.User_Playlist.load(textpath);

        user1.User_Playlist.shuffle(40);

        Stream.Users.add(user1);

        Stream.userList();
```

Attempt:

```
public void load(Path textpath){
    if (textpath != null){
        try {

            File playlistFile = new File(textpath);

            Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(playlistFile);

            System.out.println("Processing playlist file " + playlistFile + ":");
```

I get an error on: `File playlistFile = new File(textpath);`

The error says: `The constructor File(Path) is  undefined`

I need help fixing this error

Comment: Have you tried calling `textpath.toFile()` instead?

Comment: Are you referring to class [`java.io.File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html) and interface [`java.nio.file.Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) ?

Comment: yes I am referring to that

Comment: Be careful about converting a `Path` to a `File`. It will, by default, only work for `Path` instances belonging to the default `FileSystem`. That's not necessarily always going to be the case as there are other implementations out there (e.g. zip, jrt, jimfs, etc.). Besides, `Scanner` has a constructor which accepts a `Path`—just use that.

Answer (score 1):

`java.io.File` does not have `Path` type constructor. You can convert `textpath` in to `String`.

```
File playlistFile = new File(textpath.toString);
```

Or you can also use `Scanner scan = new Scanner(textpath);`

Comment: The `Path#getParent()` method returns `Path`. This will lead to the exact same problem the OP is currently having. If you want to use a `File` constructor then use `new File(nioPath.toString())` or, preferably, use `Path#toFile()` as described in the duplicate.